# How to change the font color (especially of number) in Netbeans IDE 8.0....?

Tags: netbeans

I tried changing the font color in netbeans and succeed. but the integer font color remains the same, ie **BLACK**. I want it to be **White**. Could any one help me out with it please....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question isn't really on-topic for StackOverflow, but Netbeans' online support can be confusing. Here is a link to their [user FAQ](http://wiki.netbeans.org/NetBeansUserFAQ).

That said, to change the font colour for integers in your code in Netbeans 8.0:

*Tools* menu → *Options* menu item → *Fonts & Colors* button → *Syntax* tab → choose *Number* from *Category* list → change colour in *Foreground* drop-down menu.

[image: Netbeans 8.0 Options Dialog open to Fonts & Colors / Syntax]